# QueryDSL isNotNull()'s SQL equivalent

Tags: jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I saw this code in some github repo. Its using QueryDSL to create an expression.

`BooleanExpression expression = QPerson.person.isNotNull();`

now what would be the equivalent of these expression in SQL (lets say oracle)?

Sorry if its a noob query.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same in SQL:

```
where person is not null
```